# "The parameter is incorrect" in crystal report viewer

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

I am dynamically creating a crystal report. When I run the program and click on a button, I get ***"Parameter is incorrect"*** information box. How can I resolve this?

> ```
> Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
> Imports CrystalDecisions.ReportSource
> Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared
> Imports CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms
> Imports System.Data.SqlClient
> Imports System.Data.OleDb
>
> Public Class Form1
>
> Dim objRpt As CrystalReport1
> Dim con As New SqlConnection
> Private Function CreateSelectQueryAndParameters() As String
>
>     Dim paramFields As ParameterFields
>     Dim paramField As ParameterField
>     Dim paramDiscreteValue As ParameterDiscreteValue
>
>     paramFields = New ParameterFields
>
>     Dim query As String = "SELECT "
>
>     Dim columnNo As Integer = 0
>
>     If CheckBox1.Checked Then
>
>         columnNo = columnNo + 1
>
>         query = query.Insert(query.Length, "pcode as Column" + columnNo.ToString())
>
>         paramField = New ParameterField()
>         paramField.Name = "col" + columnNo.ToString()
>         paramDiscreteValue = New ParameterDiscreteValue()
>         paramDiscreteValue.Value = "Property Code"
>         paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue)
>
>         paramFields.Add(paramField)
>     End If
>
>     If CheckBox2.Checked Then
>
>         columnNo = columnNo + 1
>         If query.Contains("Column") Then
>
>             query = query.Insert(query.Length, ", ")
>         End If
>
>         query = query.Insert(query.Length, "pname as Column" + columnNo.ToString())
>
>         paramField = New ParameterField()
>         paramField.Name = "col" + columnNo.ToString()
>         paramDiscreteValue = New ParameterDiscreteValue()
>         paramDiscreteValue.Value = "Property Name"
>         paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue)
>         paramFields.Add(paramField)
>     End If
>     For i As Integer = columnNo To 2
>
>         columnNo = columnNo + 1
>
>         paramField = New ParameterField()
>         paramField.Name = "col" + columnNo.ToString()
>         paramDiscreteValue = New ParameterDiscreteValue()
>         paramDiscreteValue.Value = ""
>         paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue)
>
>         paramFields.Add(paramField)
>     Next
>
>     CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields
>
>     query += " FROM propdb"
>     TextBox1.Text = query
>
>     Return query
>
> End Function
> Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
>
>     Dim cnn As SqlConnection
>     Dim connString As String
>     Dim query As String
>     connString = "Data Source=RANJITHA-PC;Initial Catalog=hrmdb;Integrated Security=True"
>     cnn = New SqlConnection(connString)
>     cnn.Open()
>     query = CreateSelectQueryAndParameters()
>     If Not query.Contains("Column") Then
>         MessageBox.Show("No selection to display!")
>         Return
>     End If
>
>     Dim adepter As New SqlDataAdapter(query, cnn)
>     Dim Ds As New DataSet2
>     adepter.Fill(Ds, "propdb")
>     MsgBox(Ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count)
>     cnn.Close()
>
>     objRpt = New CrystalReport1()
>     objRpt.SetDataSource(Ds.Tables(0))
>
>     Me.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt
>
>     Me.CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
> End Sub
>
> Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
>
> End Sub End Class
> ```

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Parameter is incorrect" crystal report viewer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789841/parameter-is-incorrect-crystal-report-viewer)

Comment: It didnt help me. Please try to solve problem in my code

Comment: You cannot ask the same question twice!!

Comment: Ok.. Please try to solve this problem

Comment: What are the names of parameters in report is self?

Comment: In sql server database name is hrmdb, table name is propdb(pcode,pname), dataset name is DataSet2, datatable name is propdb(Column1,Column2). I have added parameters(col1,col2).

Comment: How many parameters you have in total?

Comment: There are two parameters in total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you have a issue in you `for-loop`, should changed to

```
 For i As Integer = columnNo+1 To 2             

        paramField = New ParameterField()           
        paramField.Name = "col" + i.ToString()
        paramDiscreteValue = New ParameterDiscreteValue()
        paramDiscreteValue.Value = ""
        paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue)

        paramFields.Add(paramField)
 Next
```

And put a break pint in `CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields` and check the parameter names

Comment: Issue was in for-loop

Comment: @user3422209: Yes, please delete the other question !! Next time, no duplicate question :) Also I recommend to have a quick look on  [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: Ya sure... I will delete. Next time I wont send duplicate questions. :)